# Logstash: Is there a way to invoke grok templates on the basis of field name

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, logstash-logback-encoder

I am using ELK with logstash-logback-encoder for pushing logs to the Logstash. Now I want to use the same stack i.e ELK with logstash-logback-encoder for analytics.

Flow:

```
API(Create User)----> Commit data to RDBMS -----> 
Callback Listener(on post persist and post update) ---> 
Logger.info("IndexName: {} . DocId: {} .User json: {}", "Customer", user.getID(), user.getJson());
```

Logger.info(); logstash-logback-encoder, will push the data to Logstash, which will push the data to ES.

My *logstash.conf* is as below:

```
input {
tcp {
 port => 5044
 codec =>  multiline {
 what => "previous"
   }
 }  
}
filter{
grok {
   match => ["message", "(?<index_name>(?<=IndexName: ).*?(?=\s))"]
   match => ["message", "(?<doc_id>(?<=DocId: ).*?(?=\s))"]
   break_on_match => false
   remove_tag => ["_grokparsefailure","multiline"]
}
mutate {
  gsub => ['message', "\t", " "]
  gsub => ['message',"\e\[(\d*;)*(\d*)m"," "]
 }
}
output {
 if [index_name] == "Customer" {
         elasticsearch {
                hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
                index => "analytics-customers"
                document_id => "%{doc_id}"
                }
         }else {
          elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
         }
      }
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   }
```

My problem is that if I want to use Logstash for analytics then I have to parse the json using grok. With the amount of table and fields that I have, the logstash.conf will became really huge.

*Is there a way by which I can apply grok templates in logstash.conf which I can invoke on the basis of index name.
Like:*

```
grok {
match => ["message", "(?<index_name>(?<=IndexName: ).*?(?=\s))"]
if(index_name=="User"){
 //Invoke User template which will fetch/create fields from passed json.
}
if(index_name=="Order"){
 //Invoke Order template which will fetch/create fields from passed json.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage to get the logs in a single line, it would be the nicest way. Because than you can  change the codec to "json_lines" and everything is parsed automatically!

Otherwise you can use IF (described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html) )

Example:

```
if [subsystem] == "http" {
    mutate{ ... }
    grok{ ... }
}
```